# Stuck on celery tutorial

Tags: python, import, celery

my folder structure is

```
proj/
    __init__.py
    celery_app.py
    tasks.py
```

my celery_app looks like

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('proj',
             broker='amqp://',
             backend='amqp://',
             include=['proj.tasks'])

# Optional configuration, see the application user guide.
app.conf.update(
    result_expires=3600,
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

and my tasks.py looks like

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery_app import app

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

@app.task
def mul(x, y):
    return x * y

@app.task
def xsum(numbers):
    return sum(numbers)
```

When I go to the command line and run

`celery -A proj worker --app=proj.celery_app:app -l info`

I get an error

> "ImportError: No module named celery_app"

when I switch it from

> from celery_app import app

to

> from .celery_app import app

Then it works! But then when I try to run from tasks import * from a python shell, I get

> ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

But then if I go back and take away the preceding . in front of celery_app, I can successfully import it. Why is this happening where I need to change how I import it for each script to run successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using absolute imports is absolutely the right thing to do. So you should keep using this import statement

```
from .celery_app import app
```

In order to fix the issue you run into when trying to import in an interactive python session, you should start your session *in the same directory that contains `proj`* and then do:

```
from proj.tasks import *
```

I've copied your code to my machine and did what I suggest above and it worked fine.

Comment: It's not working for me for some reason.. do you think it has to do with using a 2.7 interpreter?

Comment: I was using 2.7. Make sure you are following my instructions exactly. Might help to start from scratch in a new directory in case there something interfering.  I've improved formatting in my answer in case that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Run those commands:

```
cd proj
celery -A proj worker --app=celery_app:app -l info
```

To run a python script correctly, you have to be in that script folder. That is why you get this error

> ImportError: No module named celery_app

Answer (score -1):

YOu can try with adding path in $PYTHONPATH variable.